# API Gateway: Can't Enable CORS

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I can't Enable CORS on my API Gateway instance, this is how it looks:

**1. Settings:**
[image]

**2. Result:**
[image]

I've tried a bunch of things like checking the `DEFAULT 4XX` and `DEFAULT 5XX` and manually inputting the Access-Control-Allow-Methods as suggested in some posts.

If I hover over the error I get: `Invalid Response status code specified`.

I'm able to GET using my browser but POST can only be done from Postman. My ReactJS website won't post either, throwing:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at <ENDPOINT> from origin <S3-REACT-BUCKET> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I've read that I have my React app should send the CORS headers (haven't got to that) but I can't even Enable CORS in the API Gateway!

Comment: Does the server accept calls from the URL?
Does the server accept the headers you send with the request?
Does the server allow GET/POST methods?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

That was because No Method Response

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manually go on the console to enable CORS. Instead follow this [guide](https://serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/) from the serverless framework.

In short:

- set `cors: true` in your http event
- return `{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*','Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true}` in your handler

Comment: I've seen this comment a lot and read through the guide. Are you sure this still works. It's a fairly simple setup but it won't work for me. I tore down the entire sls stack and redeployed with just a single function and the cors: true. Returned the headers in the Lambda but request still blocked

Answer (score 0):

You can unselect the methods  except options and then change the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and then click on the enable cors button .there wont be any changes even after you enabled it just redeploy your apis it might work.this worked for me

https://medium.com/geekculture/simple-steps-to-enable-cors-in-api-gateway-through-console-cloud-formation-c09d9df31c07